# JPanel not showing in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make an application which will allow you to create and play and Jeopardy! board. While creating the GUI I seem to have hit a road bump. A JPanel (scrollPanel1) does not seem to be showing up in my JScrollPane (scrollPanel1). I'm pretty sure that the JScrollPane is there because when I set the Scroll Bar Policy to always show the scrollbars the scrollbars are visible. But I don't think the JPanel is showing up within. I would appreciate some help.

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CreateNewBoardGUI {
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel boardInfo;
    private JLabel boardNameLabel;
    private JTextField boardNameField;
    private JTabbedPane catTab;
    private JPanel tabPanel1;
    private JPanel catNamePanel1;
    private JLabel catNameLabel1;
    private JTextField catNameField1;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane1;
    private JPanel scrollPanel1;
    private JPanel qPanel1;
    private JLabel qLabel1;
    private JTextField qField1;

    public void CreateNewBoardGUI(){
        mainFrame = new JFrame("Create new Jeopardy! board");
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        boardInfo = new JPanel();
        boardNameLabel = new JLabel("What would you like this board to be called?");
        boardNameField = new JTextField();
        catTab = new JTabbedPane();
        tabPanel1 = new JPanel();
        catNamePanel1 = new JPanel();
        catNameLabel1 = new JLabel("What would you like the category to be called?");
        catNameField1 = new JTextField();
        scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPanel1 = new JPanel();
        qPanel1 = new JPanel();
        qLabel1 = new JLabel("200 Point Question");
        qField1 = new JTextField();

        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        boardInfo.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        tabPanel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        catNamePanel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        scrollPanel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainFrame.setSize(700, 900);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

        qPanel1.add(qLabel1);
        qPanel1.add(qField1);
        scrollPanel1.add(qPanel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        scrollPane1.add(scrollPanel1);
        tabPanel1.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        catNamePanel1.add(catNameField1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        catNamePanel1.add(catNameLabel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        tabPanel1.add(catNamePanel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(catTab, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        boardInfo.add(boardNameField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        boardInfo.add(boardNameLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(boardInfo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainFrame.add(mainPanel);

        catTab.addTab("Category 1", tabPanel1);





    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a suggestion that doesn't exactly answer your question: either subclass JPanel or separate your code into methods for each panel. This will make your code much more readable when you ask questions like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();`

and add this instead(after creating scrollPanel1 instance):

`scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(scrollPanel1);`

This will force the scrollPane1 to have scrollPanel1 as its 'viewport'.

To see how things are going you should set a background color:
`scrollPanel1.setBackground(Color.red);`
Add different colors to the pannel to study their behaviour.

It should add the scrollbar as soon as you stretch it out of the tab panel.

Note: Take a look into the 'null layout'. It should be easier to deal with.

Let me know if this helps or if you still have any trouble.

Comment: I have found borders to be quite helpful in debugging layout issues:
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 5));

Comment: Thanks for giving me the quick and dirty....when you're doing a one-off sometimes you want it just work, you know you're already working with a deprecated tool set anyways

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class MainGrid {

    public static JPanel addPanel(int count) {
        JPanel newPanel = new JPanel();
        newPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 5));
        JButton jb1 = new JButton("Button 1" + count);
        jb1.setSize(200, 10);
        newPanel.add(jb1);
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("Button 2" + count);
        jb2.setSize(200, 10);
        newPanel.add(jb2);
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("Button 3" + count);
        jb3.setSize(200, 10);
        newPanel.add(jb3);
        JButton jb4 = new JButton("Button 4" + count);
        jb4.setSize(200, 10);
        newPanel.add(jb4);
        JButton jb5 = new JButton("Button 5" + count);
        jb5.setSize(200, 10);
        newPanel.add(jb5);
        newPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black, 2));
        newPanel.setVisible(true);
        return newPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("BoxLayout Test");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainPanel);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(1));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(2));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(3));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(4));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(5));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(6));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(7));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(8));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(9));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(10));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(11));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(12));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(13));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(14));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(15));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(1));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(2));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(3));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(4));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(5));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(6));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(7));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(8));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(9));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(10));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(11));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(12));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(13));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(14));
        mainPanel.add(addPanel(15));
        scrollPane.setViewportBorder(
                BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```